# OpenVPN Client Connect 2.5 (Windows) Profile Location

Tags: openvpn

It seems OpenVPN changed or removed the file location for storage of the profiles.  I've searched through the docs, changelog, and a client PC for the folder location but cannot find it for the life if me!  Where are profiles being stored now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that profiles are being stored in the following location:

`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\OpenVPN Technologies\OpenVPN Client\etc\profile`

Though you cannot simply drop a profile into here and expect it to pop up in the client anymore.

Answer (score 9):

On Windows 10, the location is:
%APPDATA%\OpenVPN Connect\profiles

Comment: Yeap, in my case it was C:\Users\%CurrentUser%\AppData\Roaming\OpenVPN Connect\profiles   , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Counterintuitively, one does not include "Roaming" in the path of the AppData variable.

```
%AppData%\OpenVPN Connect\profiles
```

The "AppData" directory variables in Windows are: `%AppData%` and `%LocalAppData%`.

Answer (score 0):

New OpenVPN stores files in:

```
[disk]:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\OpenVPN Connect\profiles
```

where `[disk]` is your system disk (in most cases `C`) and `USERNAME` is your username.

Comment: Same answer has been done 5 years ago!

Answer (score -1):

OpenVpn Connect v.3.3.4
%AppData%\Roaming\OpenVPN Connect\profiles